# Why does this function only work with exact numbers?

Tags: functions, matrix, pure-function

First, I tried calculating `A^k` with this and got an error.

```
A= {{-0.5, 3}, {0, -0.8}};
MatrixFunction[#^k &, A] // 
  FullSimplify[#, k > 0 && k \[Element] Integers] & // MatrixForm
```

*MatrixFunction::fnnum: Unable to compute the matrix function because the function #1^k& at a numeric value is not numeric.*

However, if you replace the numbers above with exact ones, it produces the correct result. Does anyone know what is happening here?

```
A = {{-1/2, 3}, {0, -4/5}};
MatrixFunction[#^k &, A]
(* {{(-1/2)^k, 5 (-1)^k 2^(1 - k) + (-1)^(1 + k) 2^(1 + 2 k) 5^(1 - k)}, {0, (-4/5)^k}} *)
```

Comment: `MatrixFunction` needs its result to be numeric if numeric values are provided, otherwise you should rationalize them to exact values. Doesn't seem to be documented. Use `MatrixPower` instead.

Comment: From documentation of `MatrifFunction`: "MatrixFunction works only on square matrices. It applies the Schur-Parlett method for inexact matrices and Jordan decomposition for exact or symbolic matrices.". If you insist on `Method -> "Jordan"` it will give you numeric result in both cases. Don't know why, though.